# Facade pattern leads to Inconsistent accessibility error

Tags: c#, facade

The code in C# should hide a complex subsystem and only expose a certain interface.

Implementing the **Facade pattern** in the below way leads to the error: *"Inconsistent accessibility: 'IService' is less accessible than constructor 'Facade'"*.

- I know that making IService(s) public solves the problem but those services should **not** be visible to the outside.

So the intention indeed is to have the facade publicly callable and the underlying services internal (hidden away).

Btw. using 'Clean architecture' so the Facade should be callable from the application layer's services.

**Questions:**

1. How should this be implemented in the correct way (so that the error goes away)?
2. Where actually should the IFacade and Facade code be placed, in the application layer or the infrastructure layer?

Thank you community!

```
public interface IFacade
{
    void TestA();
    void TestB();
}

public class Facade : IFacade
{
    private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;
    private readonly IServiceB _serviceB;

// --> HERE is the error:
    public Facade(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB)
    {
        _serviceA = serviceA;
        _serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    public void TestA()
    {
        _service.DoA1();
        _service.DoA2();
    }

    public void TestB()
    {
        _service.DoA();
    }
}

internal interface IServiceA
{
    void DoA1();
    void DoA2();
}

internal class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    public void DoA1() { }
    public void DoA2() { }
}


internal interface IServiceB
{
    void DoB1();
}

internal class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    public void DoB1() { }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect people to instantiate the Facade without being able to see the types that are taken in the parameters?

Comment: Well if you want the services to not be visible then the facade shouldn't take them as constructor parameters in the first place. Why did you think the facade should take services as parameters?

Comment: Or make the constructor internal... it's unclear at the moment how you expect the facade to be created in the first place.

Comment: Actually the problem has nothing to do with Facade pattern. how do you expect someone to call this public constructor from different assembly? How will they supply the parameters?

Comment: you should make the interfaces public. Facade is not about hiding things, its about wrapping complex chain in one call, a chain of events that could otherwise be called one by one. When understanding these patterns always stick to real world design problems.

Comment: hmm, true, always thinking about 'just injecting the dependencies' made me not thinking about that at all. Didn't see the tree in that forest :/ What about my second question, do you guys think the facade should reside in the infra layer with the other services or should it be placed in the app layer? I tend to infra.

Comment: Depends on what facade is for, in most cases it should be with all the other regular services.